# Continuity of Multivariable Piecewise Functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, piecewise-continuity

Let's say we have a function

> $$f(a,b) = \begin{cases} a &,ab \geq 0\\0 &,ab < 0\end{cases}$$

Is this function going to be continous everywhere since the limit of $f(a,b)$ equals $f(a,b)$ everywhere, or is there an exception when $ab = 0$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! [Here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a MathJax tutorial :) What've you tried so far and where did you got stuck? Please include any further details with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3532260/edit)!

Comment: For example, what is $\lim_{(a,b)\to (1,0)} f(a,b)$? In this limit we have $a>0$ but depending which side we come from we have $b>0$ or $b<0$.

Comment: Thank you. It makes a lot of sense now :)